# Does Java have it's own built-in JSON parser

Tags: java, json

Currently I use Gson for parsing JSON data. Some online tools for testing code allow you to write Java code but don't provide any means of importing packages. CoderPad is one site. Does Java have any built in JSON parser? I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no JSON parser in Java. There's a [proposal](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/198) on such feature (see also [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046390)), but it's not yet assigned to any JDK version.

Comment: That's pretty sad considering the wide usage of JSON that's been going on for years.

Comment: @AndroidDev, it's not a big problem given the fact that there are tons of third-party libraries available. You know, Java standard library is somewhat conservative (they added Base64 only in Java 8)! That's probably because if you add something, you cannot change or remove it since then, so you have to design the API very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no and will perhaps be no in JAVA 9 as well

Answer (score 0):

Java EE 7 has [JSON classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html) related to the pertaining [JSR 353](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=353) (there also in an [overview article on oracle's web presence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html)).

I cannot provide more but the sheer references as i have never worked with this interface.